# What is the fastest way to sort Javascript objects in the browser with access WebWorkers

Tags: javascript, sorting, browser, web-worker, typed-arrays

What is the fastest way to sort javascript objects when I have access to WebWorkers?  Given an array of objects like so:

```
[
  {
    otherKey: "cool", 
    name: "A. A., Ai of the FilipinosDemocratic Council of the Board Games"
  },
  {
  otherKey: "cool",
  name: "C. B., Phantom of the RaxacoricofallapatoriansEngrossing Company of the Fire Lands"
  },
  ...
]
```

My method for sorting is to take 1,000,000 of the above objects, splicing them into separate arrays (the number == the number of CPU cores == WebWorkers), sending them to the WebWorkers to be individually sorted in parallel, sent back to the ui thread to be combined back into a single array and then finally sorted on the ui thread one last time.  This over takes the performance of a single threaded sort which happens on the ui thread at about 700,000 items and roughly matches the performance somewhere between 500k and 600k.  It fluctuates.

I have 16 cores on my work machine.  Firefox seems to choke on any utilization above 12 WebWorkers but performs the fastest by besting Chrome and Safari at 8 WebWorkers.  The performance suffers if objects are much bigger than I've posted above but I'd really like to increase it considering I am attempting to keep the ui thread completely free for ui work for jank free browsing.  I understand that this is a little extreme but it would be nice to see if I've actually hit the boundary or not.

I have tried in order from fastest to slowest:

1. `postMessage()` with a JSON serialized object.
2. `postMessage()` with a JSON serialized object TextEncoded to a Uint8Array to enable transferring.
3. `postMessage()` with a JSON serialized object TextEncoded to a Uint8Array then copied to a SharedArrayBuffer (because you can't TextEncode.encode directly to a SharedArrayBuffer).
4. `Crying()`.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.  I originally thought utilizing ArrayBufferBacked Objects would be fast but I don't think they're meant for this purpose because they're slower than my SharedArrayBuffer technique.
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/buffer-backed-object

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How big a dataset are we talking about? Doing the serialization/deserialization yourself will probably be slower than the built-in structured-cloning. As for what's the fastest way to sort your data between a single thread and multiple-threads, it will probably depend on the size of the data. Starting full worker environments takes time, splitting the data and recombining too. Also, be sure to use less threads than available, otherwise you'll force task-switching instead of real parallelism, and your browser may already use several threads even without Workers.

Comment: Well, there's 1,000,000 of those objects and they're going to be about 90-110 bytes each so 100MB  for the entire data set.  Thanks to you I found that I don't even need to serialize the object arrays beforehand but it is overall slower than when I do serialize the arrays of objects.  I have also found an increase in speed up to 16 workers I haven't tested more than that but I have tested at each step fewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also kinda looking into this type of problem.
As I understand, I/O operations between the main thread and web workers are not so fast.
So, I guess you might wanna send only the indexes of the sorted items back from the workers, and then manage the array on the main thread.